# PHP DOMDocument does not keep numeric presentation of HTML special characters

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, special-characters

I have a DOMDocument and would like to append some nodes.

In one of the nodes, I would like to put:

```
$copyrightStatementText = "&#x000A9; This is the CopyRight";
```

The problem is that the function:

```
$copyrightStatement = $dom_output->createElement('copyright-statement', $copyrightStatementText);
```

Is converting the `&#x000A9;` immediately to ©.

My goal is to keep the `&#x000A9;`

Any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DOMDocument::createElement()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php):

> Note:
>   The `value` will ***not*** be escaped. Use [DOMDocument::createTextNode()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php) to create a text node with ***escaping support***.

So use [DOMDocument::createTextNode()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php) instead:

```
$copyrightString = "&#x000A9; This is the Copyright";
$copyrightNode = $dom_output->createTextNode($copyrightString);
$copyrightContainer = $dom_output->createElement('copyright-statement');

$copyrightContainer->appendChild($copyrightNode);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @André, but how can I apply the "copyright-statement" attribute to the createTextNode ?

Comment: @Milos The first parameter to `createElement()` defines the tag name for your element, so assuming you actually want a `<copyright-statement></copyright-statement>` tag, you could first create the empty element using `createElement()` and then add the text node created with `createTextNode()` as a child. See my updated answer.

Comment: I got it. Another problem appears now: the amparsan from `&#x000A9;` is also converted to `&amp` and should not be. So, I am getting `&amp;#x000A9;`. Any idea?

Comment: Strange, In my case, this is generating the `&amp`

Comment: @Milos How are you viewing the output? I assumed you are generating XML based on the "xml" tag, but if you're looking at the results in a browser it's conceivable that the browser is encoding the ampersand *while viewing*. Have you verified that the source XML document contains `&#x000A9;` vs. `&amp;#x000A9;`? If you inspect the source of the generated ouput from [my sample code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/81wOH3) you can see that it is indeed `&#000A9;`.

Comment: I ma generating a .xml file and viewing it in Notepad++, so the ampersand should not be converted in &amp; Right?